# How to connect Exchange Web Services via java web service client?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am using JWebService framework to connect my Exchange Server 2007. As it is a paid version, I am looking for some open source like JWebService.

Can anyone suggest a good alternative Java API that is free?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is it that you need help with? Your question is very open ended. What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: I am using jwebservice to communicate my EWS. I need some opensource like jwebservice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi and http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/