# Get global list of contacts from MS Exchange 2007

Tags: java, exchange-server

I have MS Exchange Server 2007 running. I have access to Outlook Web Access. I need to write a servlet, which will:

- get global list of contacts
- get personal calendar for each contact

WHat should I start with? What else do I need for that?

Can anyone suggest some tutorials / guides how can I do it? 
I'm a newbie to MS Exchange Server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work with Outlook Web Access. It is a client that connects to Exchange server and it does not offer an API. You should be connecting to the exchange server directly.

Please see the following for more info on possible technologies that can be used:
http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2007/01/30/how-do-i-access-my-outlook-contacts-from-my-web-application.aspx

The first part has a brief explanation and good info.
The example are in .NET

Since you will be working in Java, the following post might help in giving you tools in java that address connecting to Exchange Server and getting data from it.

[Open source java library to read outlook emails, calendar etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324856/open-source-java-library-to-read-outlook-emails-calendar-etc)

And two other commercial products from the same company:
http://www.moyosoft.com/jbex/
http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Exchange Server configuration you might want to try this [Exchange Web Service (EWS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190904(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Also some examples can be found @SO: [How to connect Exchange Web Services via java web service client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425990/how-to-connect-exchange-web-services-via-java-web-service-client)

Please be aware that even [version 1.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2013/01/03/ews-java-api-1-2-get-started.aspx) does not provide all the features Outlook itself has and has some bugs around calendar items -  but for mails it works usually quite well.